# Unicode file functions using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, io

I am trying to read a Unicode text file and write the data read back into a text file. Here is the code. The read works fine. I can tell because it shows a false character on the console but the output text file is empty. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int main() {
    wchar_t *filename=L"normal.txt";
    FILE *infile;
    infile=_wfopen(filename,L"r");
    wchar_t  b[2];
    fwscanf(infile,L"%ls",b);
    wprintf(L"The string read was :%ls\n",b);//Read a character from the file
    FILE *outfile;
    wchar_t *filetwo = L"one.txt";
    outfile=_wfopen(filetwo,L"w, ccs=UTF-16LE");
    fwprintf(outfile,L"%ls",b);
    fclose(outfile);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I need to deal with Devanagari scripts in particular. How many bytes do they take? If it's 4, any clues on how to deal with those using `wchar_t` because it is only 2 bytes wide.

Comment: Also, note that a wchar_t cannot portably hold a Unicode code-point value, as on some platforms it's only 16 bits.

Comment: nitpick: "Unicode" does not specify binary representation, so you can't really have such text file (well, except as general non-specifc qualifier). Does the file use UTF8, UTF16 or some other encoding?

Comment: You will need to have to handle multi-word codepoints specially, yes, either by using a Unicode library or by encoding and decoding those surrogates yourself.

Comment: @hyde The source code in the question says UTF-16LE, which is, if the text files follow the standard to the letter, BOM-less little-endian UTF-16. So no problem there for Visual C++.

Comment: Devanagiri is in the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) which holds code points between U+0000 and U+FFFF.  The main Devanagiri characters are in the range U+0900 to U+097F; there is also a Devanagiri Extended range U+A8E0 to U+A8FF.  All these should be OK in 2-byte `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devanagari codepoints are all in the BMP (you have the main block at U+0900 and some additional ones at U+A8F0), so if the text files are encoded as UTF-16, all the characters take up only one 16-bit word each.
(Don't assume that's always going to be the case though.)

Answer (score 1):

Only answering the second question:

Devanagari script characters are in [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). They are all 16-bit wide, so you're safe there. Otherwise you would have to mess with [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_pair).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!!
I just needed to open the file in binary mode.Some characters apparently get ignored otherwise.
Thanks a tonne for all the help guys!

Comment: ...What?  In text mode, system newlines are converted to C newlines, which _kindof_ looks like it's ignoring characters.  Was the character you were trying to read the character with values 10 or 13?

Comment: @MooingDuck If the file is UTF-16 then the file must be opened in binary mode because you don't want, for example, half a character to be converted from what looks like a single narrow newline character into CRLF. Also on windows there's a special byte pattern that can be used to indicate the end of a text file and which can appear in the middle of UTF-16 data.

Comment: @MooingDuck For example see the final bullet in the C++11 standard 22.5/5.

Comment: @bames53: oh right, forgot that the newline thing screws up non-ascii compatible formats.